# An example where we know the number of factors but have no idea about factor loadings

Tags: factor-analysis

In my understanding, exploratory factor analysis (EFA) is used for discovering latent structure among variables. It consists of two interrelated parts:

1. determine the number of latent factors $k$,
2. determine the loadings of factors onto variables.

However, it has been suggested (in the [comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/553545/when-are-latent-analyses-useful/553557?noredirect=1#comment1017982_553557) in another thread) -- unless I misinterpreted it -- that EFA is primarily about part 2, while part 1 can be taken as given. That does not sound quite right to me. If we know what the variables in the dataset measure and we know $k$ ahead of seeing the actual data, then with some subject-matter expertise* we probably can guess what the factors could be and consequently guess something about the loadings, too, e.g. which loadings will be close to zero. If so, we could do confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) right away instead of doing EFA.

Could you offer any example where we realistically know the number of latent factors $k$ ahead of seeing the data but have no idea about factor loadings?

*Yes, this relies on subject-matter expertise and on the number of factors $k$ not being too high. If we have a dataset where we do not know what the variables are measuring, or it comes from an area in which we have zero subject matter expertise, then knowing $k$ will not help with factor loadings.

Comment: `setting some of the loadings to zero`. If by that you mean rounding to 0 or 1, then it is definitely wrong, no such goal exists; loadings are what reconstruct correlations and help compute factor scores, so we want them as they are. But if you mean a factor rotation, then yes, it does has the aim to make loading distribution some polymodal, better bimodal, with some loadings near zero; that helps interpretation.

Comment: @ttnphns, agree, I had it wrong. I was correcting this while you posted your comment.

Comment: For k. To be able to estimate loadings, FA needs either to know k, or to know real/best communalities. These two parameters are interrelated. FA itself, in the narrow sense of the procedure, does not estimate them. They are suggested by appropriate methods (which are not one) and are input. Typically, we start with initial communalities as the sq. mult. corr. coefs, and with k suggested by rules such as Kaiser's or Cattell's or a "parallel procedure".

Comment: (cont.) Extracted factors we usually rotate. Then a number of criteria, two most important being (a) reconstruction of corr., (b) interpretability, can suggest to modify the value of k. Then we repeat with this new k. Then maybe again.

Comment: So, we find the best k by trying out different values of it. It is not FA algorithm itself what finds k for us. (Only in case you know true/optimal communalities in advance, then k is determined, comes out, automatically. But where will you get such communalities from?)

Comment: @ttnphns, I think my understanding agrees with your characterization. Many algorithms of factor extraction require $k$ as an input. However, I do not equate these algorithms with EFA. My understanding is that the definition of EFA includes the step of selecting $k$ based on the data being analyzed, among other things. To say that EFA starts only after having selected $k$ would seem wrong to me.

Comment: `If we know k ahead of seeing the data, then we probably can guess something about the loadings` How? And why some should be close to zero? An if yes, how many should be? Who can suggest it?

Comment: Richard, factor analysis algorithm does not estimate k. Factor analysis as a method of research includes (a path to) deciding on k. Will we now concur?

Comment: @ttnphns, I concur on your last comment. Regarding the previous one: If the dataset comes without meaningful variable names and we do not know what is being measured there, knowing $k$ will not help at all. What I had in mind (perhaps I should have made this explicit) is a situation where we know what the variables measure. Then we can start guessing how to summarize them in terms of 2 factors vs. 3 factors vs. 4 factors. (More than that probably will not work.) Subject-matter expertise is what is employed in the process.

Comment: @ttnphns, I am clearly learning in the process, so I have updated the question again. But by now it is probably misleading to refer to your comment the way I do, as it was probably not meant in the way I am interpreting it?

Comment: `If so, we could do confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) right away instead of doing EFA` Sure we could. I cannot figure out how exactly you are going to guess how to spread high and zero loadings over the items; but in case you've got an idea or picked the loading structure from a past research, - then of course you can bypass EFA and go right to CFA.